# Magento admin File Upload not saving the file and path

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Just a continuation of my study about magento admin grid. I'm trying to create a File Upload. The save process was complete with **NO errors** and a table row was added on database.

#### The problem:

File path was not save on the database.

Directory path was not created and off course no file was uploaded to the server.

**Note**: The process was completed with additional table row in the grid and database.

I just reference from this link [Magento image upload form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734281/magento-image-upload-form-field)

#### QUESTION:

1. How do I create a directory folder for my uploaded file?
2. How do I save the path on the database table?
3. Is there a code to be added in the config.xml?

## **UPDATE**

**Finally I solved the file upload problem.
Thanks to @PHP Weblineindia for guiding me.
Here is my updated controller.**

```
public function saveAction() {
    $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if ($post_data) {
        try {                
     //save file to the destination folder   
            if (isset($_FILES)){
                if ($_FILES['file_path']['name']) {

                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'rts' . DS .'pmadmin'.DS;
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_path');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('PDF','pdf'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $destFile = $path.$_FILES['file_path']['name'];
                    $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                    $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                    $post_data['file_path']='rts/pmadmin/'.$filename;
                }
            }
    //save file path to the database
            $model = Mage::getModel("pmadmin/pmadmin")
            ->addData($post_data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
            ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("File was successfully saved"));
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setPmadminData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            return;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setPmadminData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
        return;
        }

    }
    $this->_redirect("*/*/");
}
```

This is my form.

```
protected function _prepareForm() {

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            )
    );

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

The path should be saved on the file_path column of the table and the file should be uploaded in the media/pmadmin directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Rodge you are trying to get file data using post data like below

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$postData['pmadmin_file'];
```

And you want to upload file type so file type is not part of post.

Try as below to get file data.

```
$file_name=$_FILES['pmadmin_file']['name'];
```

and test that is you get file name in your saveAction() method, after that you can able to store file data. in directory.

In your controller file u have save data like

if(isset($imgFilename))

```
    $newsModel->setImage($imgFilename);

                $newsModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                    ->setShort_description($postData['short_description'])
                    ->setCustomer_group_id($postData['customer_group_id'])
                    ->setIs_active($postData['is_active'])
                    ->setValue($postData['value'])
                ->save();
```

Try to save Data like

if(isset($imgFilename)) {

```
        $newsModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            ->setTitle($postData['title'])
            ->setFilePath($imgFilename)
            ->setShortDescription($postData['short_description'])
            ->setCustomerGroupId($postData['customer_group_id'])
            ->setIsActive($postData['is_active'])
            ->setValue($postData['value'])
            ->save();
```

}

Comment: Thanks again @PHP Weblineindia, I'm a little bit confuse about your answer. So you mean I will change $postData['pmadmin_file']; into $file_name=$_FILES['pmadmin_file']['name'];? or where do I put the code $file_name=$_FILES['pmadmin_file']['name'];?

Comment: I mean to say that where you try to get file name like $postData['pmadmin_file']  replace that with  $_FILES['pmadmin_file']['name'];  in your saveAction() method of your controller  and then try :)

Comment: @rodge now print the file name check if that is displaying or not :) and i think there is error in ur save data. so for that i will put new answer so you can easily understand and visualize that thing.

Comment: and can u please tell me about  what are the field name that u have in your database

Comment: I'm not good in debugging but I var_dump($file_name); and I got null before the error page display the error log. "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in "

Comment: These are my table columns, pmadmin_id, title, file_path, short_description, customer_group_id, is_active, value, creation_time, update_time

Comment: @rodge first thing is that make field_name should be same in database and form field that may help you to avoid errors like if u want to upload file then your field should same in db also.